# What is the simplest approach to creating an XML document from a series of DB tables accessed via EF

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What is the simplest approach to creating an XML document from a multiples tables from a database ie: Orders > OrderItems < Products .... may be :

```
<Order id="1">
  <OrderItem id ="1">
    <Product>Wheel</Product>
    <Qty>1<Qty/>
    <Price>10.00</Price>
  </OrderItem>
<Order>
```

I need it in XML to transform to XHTML for loading into Word.

I am also using MVC3, EF5.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give a ton of detail, but you could use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class.  You could string writer if you're only wanting to output to a string instead.

A code sample from MSDN:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = 
   new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem));

   // Create an instance of the class to be serialized.
   OrderedItem i = new OrderedItem();

   // Set the public property values.
   i.ItemName = "Widget";
   i.Description = "Regular Widget";
   i.Quantity = 10;
   i.UnitPrice = (decimal) 2.30;

   // Writing the document requires a TextWriter.
   TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);

   // Serialize the object, and close the TextWriter.
   serializer.Serialize(writer, i);
   writer.Close();
```

Comment: Mark, Huge thanks for this. I really wanted a pointer to a technology/tool/component that I can use at runtime in my code to easily create an XML document from some related tables, and be able to represent those same master-detail type relationships in the XML document. This is all governed by a query on a master entity, ie for Orders where ID =1, provide all related OrderItem data, and related data such as Products. From what you write the technology that I need to focus on is the XmlSerializer Class.